# How to schedule raspberry pi to shutdown every day at a certain time?

Tags: shutdown

I’m trying to schedule my pi 3b+ (buster) to shutdown automatically at a certain time, but it’s not listening to me. What am i doing wrong?

```
Sudo crontab -e
```

Then i add (nano) this to bottom of the file:

```
36 08 * * * sudo /sbin/shutdown –h now
```

This should tell it to shutdown everyday at 8:36am, correct?

Comment: Try adding a `@reboot shutdown -h 08:36` line. Which uses the shutdown command's scheduler.

Comment: Not working. Also tried adding that in autostart file. No luck.

Comment: I got it. It was setting it to occur the following day. I had been setting it for a few mins after current time to test it, which wasn’t working because it was setting it to occur 24 hrs later. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Open `crontab` by `crontab -e` or `export VISUAL=nano; crontab -e` which is much easier to edit. Then, add the line below at the end of that:

```
@reboot /sbin/shutdown -h 08:36
```

---

You can also follow your procedure that mentioned. Gonna work.